# When creating a branch for a new feature, once merged into master, how to delete?

Tags: git

I created a branch just for a feature, and now I am in the master branch, and I did a merge.

I don't really need this branch now, how can I delete it?

I pushed my code to a remote git server, but I believe the remote git doesn't pickup my local branches since I didn't tell it to right?

Comment: Did you even consider Googling `git delete branch`?

Comment: yes, just wanted to make sure it was a good idea or not.

Comment: You're correct that the remote doesn't have the feature branch, but it does have the commits that are/were on it, since they were merged into master and then pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
git branch -d [branch name]
```

Comment: If the named branch isn't merged into the current branch, Git will tell you, and refuse to delete it, so this is a reasonably safe command, as far as deletion goes. (`git branch -D` will bypass those safeguards.)